# Regex working on regex101 but not in Vscode snippet

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I am struggling with a regex that works fine on regex101: https://regex101.com/r/Hhj2l9/1, but not in a vscode snippet for html.

From the following string: `C:\folder0\folder1\folder2\libtest\folder3\folder4\folder5`

I get the following results on regex101: `libtest/libfolder3/libfolder4/folder5`, which is what I want.

In my snippet:

```
lib${TM_DIRECTORY/(?:.*lib)?([^\\\\.*]*)\\\\/$1\\//g}
```

The result below in the html:

```
lib${TM_DIRECTORY/(?:.*lib)?([^\.*]*)\/\//g}
```

Has anyone an idea on how to make it work in a vscode snippet?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
"${TM_DIRECTORY/(?:.*[\\\\\\/]lib)?([^\\\\\\/]+)[\\\\\\/]/lib$1\\//g}"
```

Here,

- `(?:.*[\\\/]lib)?` - matches an optional occurrence of any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible, and then `\` or `/` and `lib`
- `([^\\\\\\/]+)` - Group 1 (`$1`): one or more chars other than `\` and `/`
- `[\\\\\\/]` - a `/` or `\`.

Comment: Great thanks a lot it works! Do you have any idea why my first attempt did not work? (I am curious to know, I am a bit of a beginner in regex)

Comment: @Benoit00 Your regex only added `lib` at the start of the text and the backslashes that match a literal backslash cannot appear immediately before the `/` regex delimiter char, so I put it into a character class, `[...]`. Also, note that `[^\\\\.*]` matches any char other than a ``\``, `.` and `*`. I think `.` and `*` are typos here.